# SQL Server : subscription : how to know if a table is under replication/subscription

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

In SQL Server, on the "Subscription side", how can you know if a table is under replication/subscription?

Any idea?

Comment: I've just built and torn down replication multiple times to try and find some answers, and I'm still not happy with what I've posted :-|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a simple answer to this, and I think the answers may vary based on the type of replication. I think you may have to rely on heuristics to answer it.

For snapshot replication, I'm unable to think of anything that would give the game away. Obviously, the presence of the replication tables (e.g. [`MSreplication_objects`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173383.aspx)) tells you that replication is occurring within the database, but there aren't any specific clues about tables, so far as I'm aware.

For transactional replication (non updating), you may be able to go via [`MSreplication_objects`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173383.aspx) (which will list some stored procs) and then use [`sys.sql_dependencies`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174402.aspx) to locate the tables that these relate to

For transaction replication (updating), you can look in [`MSsubscription_articles`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189500.aspx) (or look for the presence of the subscription updating triggers against the table)

For merge replication, you can look in [`sysmergearticles`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189825.aspx), but you'd also have to look in [`sysmergesubscriptions`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182728.aspx) to determine that you're on the subscription side.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the subscriber database check for the table `dbo.MSreplication_subscriptions`. If the database is `subscriber`, you will find this table. Also, to find out articles use this in the `subscribed` database

```
SELECT publisher,Publisher_Db,publication,article
FROM dbo.MSreplication_objects
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [Damien the Unbeliever's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4744671/1501497) (+1) to produce this code that worked for me

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ot.object_id
    ,ot.schema_id
    ,r.publisher
    ,r.publisher_db
    ,r.publication
    ,r.article
FROM 
    dbo.MSreplication_objects R
        INNER JOIN sys.objects so ON r.object_name = so.name AND so.type = 'P' --stored procedures
        INNER JOIN sys.sql_dependencies dp ON so.object_id = dp.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.objects ot ON dp.referenced_major_id = ot.object_id  --objects
                                AND r.article = ot.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to create a linked server to the main server and query the table `[distribution].[dbo].[MSarticles]`.

`select * from [distribution].[dbo].[MSarticles]`

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at DATABASEPROPERTYEX.  It has an 'IsSubscribed' option that should do what you want it to do.

Comment: That will tell you if the database is a subscriber, but won't let you determine which tables are part of the subscription. Subscription databases can contain their own tables which aren't part of the publication.

Comment: Whoops... you're right.  I misread the question as "how to tell if a database is a subscriber".